# Is it possible to specify a private member variable public only for const operations?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, member-variables

I have a member variable, `enabled_m`, whose value is dependent on a number of variables. Since these invariants should be maintained by the class, I want it to be `private`:

```
class foo_t
{
public:
    void set_this(...); // may affect enabled_m
    void set_that(...); // may affect enabled_m
    void set_the_other_thing(...); // may affect enabled_m

    bool is_enabled() const { return enabled_m; }

private:
    bool enabled_m;
};
```

Which works, but really my intent is to require a user of `foo_t` to go through the class to *modify* `enabled_m`. If the user wants to just *read* `enabled_m`, that should be an allowable operation:

```
bool my_enabled = foo.enabled_m; // OK
foo.enabled_m = my_enabled; // Error: enabled_m is private
```

Is there a way to make `enabled_m` `public` for `const` operations and `private` for non-`const` operations, all without having to require a user go through accessor routines?

Comment: What's wrong with using a getter function? If your concern is efficiency, an `inline` function that returned a `const bool&` would probably compile down to the same thing as direct member access.

Comment: You can probably create some kind of proxy object that points to your "real" bool - but is it really worth it? A getter is the most popular and clean solution.

Comment: On top of @dlf's concerns, I think the interface duality would make things confusing even if you could do that.

Comment: @dlf there's nothing wrong with an accessor routine per se. In the specific case I'm working on, were I to add an accessor routine, I'd have to touch a significant portion of my code base which uses `enabled_m` in `const` operations. I'm trying to minimize the maintenance cost of adding accessor routines and their reach throughout my code base.

Comment: @dlf: for `bool` you probably want to return by value anyway...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Usually; I'm not sure what effect that would have on inlining, though. Probably none, I suppose, if the optimizer knows what it is doing.

Comment: I've often wanted this... it's definitely useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's no way to restrict modification only to members. `private` restricts all access to the name; `const` prevents modification everywhere.

There are some grotesque alternatives (like a `const` reference, or use of `const_cast`), but the accessor function is the simplest and most idiomatic way to do this. If it's inline, as in your example, then its use should be as efficient as direct access.

Comment: That was my line of reasoning, too - just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: The term grotesque seems overdevalorizing a valid construct. However i agre that it's better not to go that way, because it could hamper future evolution of the class (f.ex going for lazy evaluation, or having a different determination n a derived class)

Comment: @Christophe: Adding a reference member would break copy semantics: the default copy constructor would give you a reference to the wrong object. I'd call that grotesque. Using `const_cast` to modify a `const` member is UB, which is unarguably grotesque.

Comment: I suppose another option would be to make the member variable `public` and `const`, and use a non-const accessor _within_ the class. That could keep things neater for clients.

Comment: @fbrereto, no, because if it's declared `const` then there's no way to modify it within the accessor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The first part or your remark applies in fact as well to classes using pointers to privately owned objects... Don't you have lots of such classes which need a user-defined copy constructor to ensure proper copy semantic ? Would you call all of them groteseque ?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I am just now discovering this is UB. Rats.

Comment: @Christophe: Yes, I also regard managing resources with raw pointers as grotesque (unless the class is specifically intended for that purpose - of which you need very few, mostly provided by the standard library). But my opinions of grotesqueness aren't particularly relevant to this question.

Answer (score 10):

Most engineers will prefer that you use accessor methods, but if you really want a hack-around, you could do something like this:

```
class AccessControl
{
private:
    int dontModifyMeBro;
public:
    const int& rDontModifyMeBro;
    AccessControl(int theInt): dontModifyMeBro(theInt), rDontModifyMeBro(dontModifyMeBro)
    {}

    // The default copy constructor would give a reference to the wrong variable.
    // Either delete it, or provide a correct version.
    AccessControl(AccessControl const & other): 
        dontModifyMeBro(other.rDontModifyMeBro), 
        rDontModifyMeBro(dontModifyMeBro)
    {}

    // The reference member deletes the default assignment operator.
    // Either leave it deleted, or provide a correct version.
    AccessControl & operator=(AccessControl const & other) {
        dontModifyMeBro = other.dontModifyMeBro;
    }
};
```

Comment: You'll need a non-default copy constructor to initialise the reference correctly; and a non-default assignment operator if you want to allow assignment.

Comment: Yep, @MikeSeymour, I imagine that's why you put this method in the "grotesque" group. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

A great deal here depends upon the intent behind exposing the enabled state, *but* my general advice would be to avoid exposing it *at all*.

The usual use of your `is_enabled` would be something like:

```
if (f.is_enabled())
    f.set_this(whatever);
```

In my opinion, it's nearly always better to just call the `set_this`, and (if the client cares) have it return a value to indicate whether that succeeded, so the client code becomes something like:

```
if (!f.set_this(whatever))
   // deal with error
```

Although this may seem like a trivial difference when you start to do multi-threaded programming (for one major example) the difference becomes absolutely critical. In particular, the first code that tests the enabled state, then attempts to set the value is subject to a race condition--the `enabled` state may change between the call to `is_enabled` and the call to `set_this`.

To make a long story short, this is usually a poor design. Just don't do it.